# FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I had this exception while authenticating multiple gmails using google auth with firebase. 
after logging in and deleting the mail data from the Authentication tab in firebase i've got this exception. After i got it i am not able to login on the app with any gmail account. Same exception keeps on returning.

`com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException ERROR_INVALID_USER_TOKEN  This user's credential isn't valid for this project. This can happen if the user's token has been tampered with, or if the user isn't for the project associated with this API key.`

Comment: have anyone able to solve this issue?

Comment: I tried some solution but no hope, so I decide reset my phone (factory reset) and tada, its work